# How to find the most recent row for each item in a Django managed database?

Tags: python, django, sorting

What is the best way to find the most recent entries in a data structure for each related object?  I have a Django models like:

```
class OtherThing(models.Model):
    pass

class Thing(models.Model):
    buddy =  models.ForeignKey(OtherThing, related_name=things)
    somedata = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm interested in getting the most recent `Thing` for each `OtherThing`.  Here is some slow and stupid code that would get the result I want:

```
latest_things = []
for other in OtherThing.models.iterator():
     latest_things.append(other.things.latest())
```

However, this is all done in the Python space, and issues many, many queries to the database.  I also tried using the [(PostGreSQL only)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) `DISTINCT ON`.  This did not appear to honor the 'id' sorting, which was my attempt to get the latest:

```
Thing.objects.order_by('buddy_id', '-id').distinct('buddy_id')
```

*Originally mistyped as `...distinct('id')`, thanks okm for pointing this out.*

**How can I find the most recent `Thing` for each `OtherThing`, preferably in a way that lets the database do most of the work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care the ordering (by OtherThing DESC instead of by Thing DESC), the following code would work fine:

```
Thing.objects.order_by('-buddy', '-id').distinct('buddy')
```

If you do, possibly you need to write a `.row()` with `IN` query or subquery or self-join such as:

```
SELECT * FROM thing_tbl WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (buddy_id) id FROM thing_tbl ORDER BY buddy_id DESC, id DESC) ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will always fetch the latest OtherThing (why would it?).

Comment: @yuvi It fetches the latest Thing (if there is any) of each OtherThing in the ordering of OtherThing desc and then Thing desc.

Comment: @yuvi To be correct: in the ordering of their (the fetched Things) OtherThing desc.

Comment: Thanks &... drat, I WAS doing this, but typoed buddy for id in my question.  I suppose I should update the question.

Comment: @dbw I see. Then I would go for the second way: a `raw()` SQL.